# C# asp.net checkbox not firing when unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have found this question a few places but no solutions...

I have a checkbox in a gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closed?">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <asp:CheckBox ID="Status_CB"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            OnCheckedChanged="Status_CB_CheckedChanged" 
            EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
            Checked='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("cStatus")) == "1" ? true : false %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!int.TryParse(Session["FacilityID"].ToString(), out FId)) {
        FId = 0;
    }
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString.Get("WorkCenter"))) {
            wc = Request.QueryString.Get("WorkCenter");
            WorkcenterHeader.InnerText = wc + " Schedule ";
            HiddenWorkCenter.Value = c;
        }
        if (!SQLHasData()) {
            SavePrioritiesToSQL();
        }
        BindGrid();
    }
}
protected void Status_CB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) cb.Parent.Parent;
}
```

When i check the box originally, it works. When i uncheck it, the breakpoint i have on the first line of Status_CB_CheckedChanged does not fire at all.

What am i missing any one know?

UPDATE - here is the table, it is nested. i wonder if that is the reason it will not call the postback on uncheck...

UPDATE - ok i gave up, this must be a bug with nested gridview in asp so if you have a nested gridview, i recommend not using checkboxes. I switched mine to a text field of the cStatus "open" or "closed" and use a button with a command argument that is the row index:

```
<asp:GridView ID="JobInfo_GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="ChildGrid2" OnRowCommand="JobInfo_GV_RowCommand">
<asp:BoundField DataField="cStatus" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center-row" ItemStyle-CssClass="center-row"/>  
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
    <ItemTemplate >
      <asp:Button id="UpdateClosed" commandname="Select" buttontype="button" Text="ToggleStatus"  runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then the C#:

```
protected void JobInfo_GV_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) {
    var grid = (GridView)sender;
    var errorMessage = string.Empty;
    if (grid != null) {
        int index = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out index) ){
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
```

Comment: I tested your code. It works just fine! Can you please post your complete aspx and c# code?

Comment: I am wondering if it's because the gridview is a templateview in a gridview then...

Comment: Please check my answer and compare it to your code. My answer works as you expect.

Comment: Updated to add my full table. Your solution works, until i wrap it in the table and then it fails

Comment: You need to set AutoPostBack="true" for the Checkbox control. your original code had that but your new code does not have it! Is'nt that the issue?

Comment: Oh no... sorry i am working on a workaround now. This has to be a bug in asp. Everytime have a nested gridview, if i find the checkbox it evaluates to true and on unchecking it, it does NOT do the postback call to the onchanged function. So now i am using buttons, finding the index, and reading a text column, storing it in the db and changing it each time the button is pressed. 
Sorry to give up but this has to be a bug in asp, idk what else it could cause it to not call a function only when unchecking it.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a project and reused your code as part of it.
It works as you expect:

**Note** you need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` for the `Checkbox` control

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Closed?">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="Status_CB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnCheckedChanged="Status_CB_CheckedChanged"
                                EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                                Checked='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("cStatus")) == "1" ? true : false %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                BindGrid();
        }

        public class DataS
        {
            public int cStatus { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        private void BindGrid()
        {
            List<DataS> list = new List<DataS>() { new DataS() { Name = "Name1", cStatus = 1 }, new DataS() { Name = "Name2", cStatus = 1 }, new DataS() { Name = "Name3", cStatus = 0 } };
            GV.DataSource = list;
            GV.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Status_CB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)cb.Parent.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the autopostback was set to true. I removed it when i started changing the solution to use textboxes and a button instead of a the bugged checkbox.  There is a workaround in the origional answer now if any one is struggling with a  checkbox in a  nested gridview